# ConcurrentHashMap getting deleted while adding elements to it

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn about multi threading. Suppose I have a class which has a method to add value to a ConcurrentHashMap.

```
public void add(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> map){
   if(!map.containsKey(1){
     map.put(1,"test");
   }
}
```

How do I make sure that a different thread in not deleting specific values or removing the entire map while I am adding elements to it.

I tried to synchronized(map) in add method but that doesn't work.

Edit 1:
I didn't frame it correctly.I meant if some other thread makes the map null and I don't have access to the code that is making it null.
How do I avoid null pointer exception in add method. 
I can test it for null after entering the method but what if it becomes null after the check but before I add contents to it.

Comment: To make your `add` method thread-safe, you should use the atomic [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) method instead of what you have now (which by the way doesn't compile).

Comment: `putIfAbsent` would make it threadsafe but i think it will not prevent me from getting the null pointer exception if the map reference is made null by another method.

Comment: If you don't have control over the client code that's using the `add` method, then there is no way to prevent `map` from being `null`. What you can do, is to communicate in the method signature that no-one should pass in a `null` value; e.g. annotate the parameter with `@NonNull`: `public void add(@NonNull ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> map)`. This will issue a warning in modern IDEs if you try to pass in a `null` value. Additionally, you can check for nullness within the method, by wrapping everything within `if (map != null) {...} `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to prevent a variable that contains a reference to a `Map` (or any other object type) from becoming null, you would need to synchronize everything that read and wrote that variable.

That would create a concurrency bottleneck, and negate any concurrency benefits of using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

The real problem here is that something is assigning null to the variable in the first place.  That makes it very difficult to share the `Map` between threads.  It is probably a flaw in your design.

This is a problem that is best solved by removing the need for the assignment.  (Or if it is accidental, finding and fixing the cause.)  Don't try and fix it by synchronization.  It is a band-aid solution, and it will make your code more complex and less concurrent.

---

> I don't have access to the code that is making it null.

Well you have a serious problem, because >>that<< code is where the "issue" is, and the fix it to change >>that<< code.

(Or, I guess, you could declare your own `final Map ...` variable, initialize it from the dodgy variable that is being nulled by the code that you can't change, and then use your one.)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "removing the need for the assignment"

Comment: I mean, redesign the code so that you never need to do this:  `mapVar = null;`  Or better still, change the declaration to `final Map mapVar = ...;`

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't 'delete the whole map' in Java. If the map becomes garbage, it becomes garbage. Second, if two threads race, *something* happens. The map will always be valid, and show the results of the two threads performing their operations in some order. That's all a concurrent map is for -- to ensure that the map is valid and consistent without requiring you to synchronize around operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `map` is just a reference to the actual object store on the heap. In Java, you can't **DELETE** an object on the heap manually, but rather the garbage collector may delete an object that is not referenced by anything else.

When you call `add`, your code in the method block actually references the object. So it will never be `null`. Moreover, you should use `putIfAbsent` to make the operation atomic.